# how to call click function of variable in document ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want trigger my click event on my menu1 on document load function. As i have many function on that menu i assigned it to a variable. And called the click event on that variable. But its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menuone = $('#menu1');
    var $menutwo = $('#menu2');
    var $menuthree = $('#menu3');
    var $menufour = $('#menu4');
    $menuone.trigger("click");

    $("#menuone").click(function () {
        $("#frm1").show();
        $("#frm3").hide();
        $("#frm4").hide();
        $("#frm2").hide();
        $(this).css({
            border: "2px solid #A69A8F",
            "border-bottom-width": "0",
            background: "#F7F7F7",
            color: "#0D638B;"
        });
        $(this).children().css({
            color: "#0D638B",
            "font-weight": "bold"
        });
    });

    $menutwo.click(function () {
        $menuone.removeAttr('style');
        $menuone.children().removeAttr('style');
        $("#frm1").hide();
        $("#frm3").hide();
        $("#frm4").hide();
        $("#frm2").show();
        $(this).css({
            border: "2px solid #A69A8F",
            "border-bottom-width": "0",
            background: "#F7F7F7",
            color: "#0D638B;"
        });
        $(this).children().css({
            color: "#0D638B",
            "font-weight": "bold"
        });        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers run your JavaScript line by line. Therefore, your binding of $("#menuone").click isn't attached at the time you trigger the click.

**Solution:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $menuone = $('#menu1');
    var $menutwo = $('#menu2');
    var $menuthree = $('#menu3');
    var $menufour = $('#menu4');

    $("#menuone").click(function () {
      $("#frm1").show();
      $("#frm3").hide();
      $("#frm4").hide();
      $("#frm2").hide();
      $(this).css({border:"2px solid #A69A8F","border-bottom-width":"0", background: "#F7F7F7",color:"#0D638B;"});
      $( this ).children().css({color: "#0D638B","font-weight":"bold"} );
    });

    $menutwo.click(function () {
      $menuone.removeAttr( 'style' );$menuone.children().removeAttr( 'style' );
      $("#frm1").hide();
      $("#frm3").hide();
      $("#frm4").hide();
      $("#frm2").show();
      $(this).css({border:"2px solid #A69A8F","border-bottom-width":"0", background: "#F7F7F7",color:"#0D638B;"});
      $( this ).children().css({color: "#0D638B","font-weight":"bold"} );

    });

    // Put it here
    $menuone.trigger("click");
});
```

*By the way, your `$menuone` isn't `$("#menuone")` but `$("#menu1")`, which I **guess** it is a typo?*

Comment: Thanks for reply but its not working for me.. Why   adding # before a variable $("#menuone").click(function () {})?

Comment: @Sami `$("#menuone")` is not `$("#menu1")` check for this, as suggested in the answer.